# Динамически добавлять данные в RecyclerView из Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Нужно чтобы при добавлении данных в Firebase в `RecyclerView` добавлялись данные после уже имеющихся. В моем коде при добавке данных в `RecyclerView` они опять повторяются.

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Body body1 = ds.getValue(Body.class);
            bodies.add(body1);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new NewOrderAdapter(getContext(),bodies));
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        bodies.clear();// очищаем коллекцию
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Body body1 = ds.getValue(Body.class);
            bodies.add(body1);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new NewOrderAdapter(getContext(),bodies));
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @Raz [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)